# MSMQ: Максимальный размер сообщения

Tags: c#, msmq

При использовании MSMQ я не могу передать сообщение больше чем **4 мб** (*ограничение*). Как мне обойти это ограничение ?

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, мы хотите использовать шину для проброски файлов. На мой взгляд использовать для этого шину не лучшая идея, однако если хочется, вот пример от Ms:

```
using System;
using System.Messaging;
using System.IO;
namespace FilesInMsmq{
    /// <summary> 
    /// This example shows how to send and receive Files larger than 4 Mb. using MSMQ Messages.
    /// How to run the example:
    /// FilesInMsmq [send/receive] [File Name] [Queue Path] 
    /// </summary> 
    class MsmqFileExample {
        //break the mesage into 4 Mb chunks  static int chunkSize = 4194000;
        [STAThread]  static void Main(string[] args)  {
            string fileName;
            string queuePath;
            if (args.Length > 0)   {
                //get parameters from command prompt  
                fileName = args[1];
                queuePath = args[2];
                switch (args[0])    {
                case "send":
                    SendFile(fileName, queuePath);
                    break;
                case "receive":
                        ReceiveFile(fileName, queuePath);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        static void SendFile(string fileName, string queuePath)  {
            int i;
            int count = 0;
            int msgNumber = 0;
            //Open an existing queue 
            MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
            Message msg = new Message();
            try   {
                //Open the file for reading    
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))    {
                    // while there are bytes     
                    while ((i = fs.ReadByte()) != -1)     {
                        // if count has reached size, send message      
                        if (count >= chunkSize)      {
                            msgNumber++;
                            msg.AppSpecific = msgNumber;
                            //Send the messsage       
                            queue.Send(msg);
                            string nextMsgId = msg.Id;
                            count = 0;
                            //Create a new message 
                            msg = new Message();
                            msg.CorrelationId = nextMsgId;
                        }
                        msg.BodyStream.WriteByte((byte)i);
                        count++;
                        // from the original file  
                    }
                    msgNumber++;
                    msg.AppSpecific = msgNumber;
                    //Send the last message  
                    queue.Send(msg);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)   {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally   {
                //release queue resources 
                queue.Close();   }
        }

        static void ReceiveFile(string fileName, string queuePath)
        {
            byte[] data;
            int length;
            //Open an existing queue  
            MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
            try   {
                //Open file for writing    
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(fileName))   {
                    //Receive the first message     
                    Message msg = queue.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1));
                    while (msg != null)     {
                        //Get the Lenght of the message body stream    
                        length = Convert.ToInt32(msg.BodyStream.Length);
                        //Create a buffer to hold the stream in memory     
                        data = new byte[length];
                        //Read the body stream    
                        msg.BodyStream.Read(data, 0, length);
                        //Write the buffer into the file    
                        fs.Write(data, 0, length);
                        //Receive following message   
                        msg = queue.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)   {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally   {
                //release queue resources    queue.Close(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, никак. Это архитектурное ограничение. Подробности [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnbreakwell/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages).

Хотя для BizTalk, который использует тот же MSMQ есть расширение, которое называется BizTalk Message Queuing Large Message Extension. [Тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnbreakwell/how-to-send-msmq-messages-over-4mb-in-size-1-using-mqrtlarge-dll) можно почитать подробнее.

Второй вариант - вручную разбивать сообщения на части. Думаю, пример реализации не составит труда нагуглить, т.к тема достаточно избита.